# A list of absurd phrases

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay

The following words/phrase belong at the beginning:

> ***Letter, Second, Confinement, Move, Logical Operation, Demise, Foyer***

---

The following words/phrases belong at the end:

> ***Number, Colour, Prohibition, Anger, Cancel, Red liquid, Common Era***

---

***This list of absurd phrases has a common theme. What is it?***

> 1. Letter's Number
> 2. Colour of Second
> 3. Confinement of Prohibition
> 4. Move of Anger
> 5. Logical Operation of the Cancel
> 6. Red Liquid Common Era
> 7. Demise Foyer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These absurd phrases are all ...

> ... titles of **[Harry Potter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter)** books.

How so?

> These titles and the "absurd phrases" all have two principal words (*The This of That* or *The Adjective Noun*). The Harry Potter titles include the corresponding absurd word at the beginning or at the end as described in the preamble. So:
>
>  Letter's Number — **Phi**losopher's St**one**
>  Colour of Second — Ch**amber** of **Sec**rets
>  Confinement of Prohibition — **Prison**er of Azka**ban**
>  Move of Anger — **Go**blet of F**ire**
>  Logical Operation of the Cancel — **Or**der of the Phoe**nix**
>  Red Liquid Common Era — Half-**Blood** Prin**ce**
>  Demise Foyer — **Death**ly **Hall**ows